# Openshift 4: oc get environment variable with name

Tags: openshift

Is there a way to get the value of a specific Openshift Service environment variable?

such as:

```
oc get <namespace>/servicename env <envname>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this:

```
oc set env dc/<applicaiton-name> --list
```